# R get the string-match

Tags: r, get, match

I swear to god I have searched the whole internet for the last 60 minutes with google searches like "r get match" ecetera. I do not want to install any librariers for this easy task. I have a string `"something1_something2"` and I want to get `something1`.

```
a<-"hi_there"
```

according to some forum entry I am supposed to get it with sub:

```
> sub("hi_", "\\1", a)
[1] "there"
```

I want to get the `"hi"`, but I cannot even seem to get the `"hi_"`. I have tried a thousand things, how do I do it ?

Comment: strsplit(x, "_")[[1]]

Comment: `gsub("(.*)_(.*)", "\\1", a)` is most likely what you are thinking of, but it would help if you describe the conditions rather than telling us the history of your searching :-)

Comment: `sub` *removes* what you match!! You actually want `sub("_there", "\\1", a)` to get `"hi"`. What you are describing is using `regmatches` to extract the matched part of a string, which would work like this: `regmatches( a , regexpr( "hi" , a ) )`. See, same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Try *strsplit* to break the string into chunks:

```
x = c("hi_there", "this#is#sparta")
chunks = strsplit(x, c("_", "#"))

# first word
print(chunks[[1]])
[1] "hi"    "there"

# second word
print(chunks[[2]])
[1] "this"   "is"     "sparta"
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be a little tricky. You need to create a capture group within a pattern that matches the whole string to replace the whole string with what is in the capture group:

```
sub("(hi)_.+","\\1",a)
[1] "hi"
```

Answer (score 1):

`regexec`/`regmaches` does this as well, though the `strsplit` approach is simpler for this particular problem.

```
a <- c("hi_there", "something_somthing", "boo_ya_yo")
sapply(regmatches(a, regexec("^([^_]*)", a)), `[[`, 2)
# [1] "hi"        "something" "boo"
```

The main advantage of this approach is if you have other requirements (e.g. you also want the leftmost piece to start with consonants, or whatever) which you can address by modifying the regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're looking in general for a substring from the start of the character vector element to the first underscore. You're only going to find one match (there's only one substring that starts the element) so `sub` is the place to go, either matching the desired string (look at the start of the string `^` capturing zero or more characters that are not the underscore `([^_]*)` that are followed by an underscore and maybe additional characters `_.*`)

```
re1 = "^([^_]*)_.*"
sub(re1, "\\1", x)
```

or dropping the stuff after the first underscore (an underscore `_` followed by zero or more of any other characters `.*`)

```
re2 = "_.*"
sub(re2, "", x)
```

with some tests

```
x = c("a_b", "a_", "_b", "a", "a_b_c", "", NA)
sub(re1, "\\1", x)
## [1] "a" "a" ""  "a" "a" ""  NA 
sub(re2, "", x)
## [1] "a" "a" ""  "a" "a" ""  NA
```

`strsplit` solutions fail on some of these.